# Notification Access Permission Not Working When App is Closed(oppo,vivo and mi)

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I'm developing an app (Notification History Log for Everyone).

I received a lot of negative reviews from the user using MIUI and Color OS saying the app is not working. I checked with Redmi Note 4 and started testing the apps.

Here is what I observed:

**Case 1: Installing for the first time.**

My app cannot read any new notifications. `onNotificationPosted` method in `NotificationListenerService` is not called at all.

**Case 2: Uninstalled the app and reinstalled again and the app is in the foreground.**

My app now started to read new notifications and `onNotificationPosted` method is called this time

**Case 3: I closed the app and app is in the background**

`onNotificationPosted` method is called only sometimes (25% times it is called)

**Case 4: Removed app from recent apps list**

`onNotificationPosted` method is never called.

---

I downloaded around 10 other apps from play store which uses the same Notification Access Permission and I observed the same problem with every app.

**Is this a bug or restriction?**

Note 1: I tested the same app with the same code on Stock Android, Oxygen, CM, TouchWiz and it is working fine without any issues.

The problem is only with Xiaomi (MIUI), Oppo (Color OS) and Vivo (FunTouch OS) devices.

I have checked with PushBullet app in the app store which uses the same notification access permission and yet works.

**Is there a workaround?**

Comment: any update ??on this